# How to combine two columns and apply binarizer?

Tags: numpy

Tried using MultiLabelBinarizer and did not work

For ex: device category (has two values - android and ios), browser (3 values chrome, safari, and IE) are two columns... If there a android value in device category and safari in browser column then binarizer column name of androd_safari will have to put the value as 1... Like this out will have 6 binarizer columns with value either 0 or 1

Do I need to write my own function or there is a built in dataframe functions that I can use

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches in normalizing the training/test set data using LocalEncoder, LabelBinarizer, but these are applied on single column

To create the binarization based on two columns (to label your data set) create a temporary DataFrame and do as below:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def two_col_binarizer(df, col1, col2):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    arcol1 = df[col1].unique()
    arcol2 = df[col2].unique()
    arbdc = np.empty((arcol1.size*arcol2.size), dtype=object)

    for i in range(arcol1.size):
        for j in range(arcol2.size):
            arbdc[i*arcol2.size+j] = arcol1[i]+arcol2[j]

    num_rows, num_cols = df.shape
    tempdf = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, num_rows), columns = arbdc)
    tempdf = tempdf.fillna(0)

    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        tempdf.at[i, df['device.deviceCategory'][i]+df['device.browser'][i]] = 1

    print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
    return tempdf

# for example your training data set has devicecategory and browser columns
df=df.join(two_col_binarizer(df, 'devicecategory', 'browser'))
```